# Connecting Azure File Share to Hybrid HPC Pack 2019 Batch Pool

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, hpc, azure-batch

With my on-premisis HPC-Pack 2019 headnode, I am able to start a new Az batch pool with no issues. I would now like this pool to start with my Azure File Share automatically mounted.

To do this via CLI, we can use the instructions posted at [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/virtual-file-mount?tabs=windows) to create a new pool. However, to connect it to the HPC-Pack scheduler, I need to use the GUI wizard provided.

[screenshot of gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wer55.png)

From the screenshot, we can see at the bottom an option to provide Mount Configuration. I *think* this field accepts JSON input only. I have tried to create a JSON object via CLI following the steps of the Link above to get somewhere like this:

```
{
    "AzureBlobFileSystemConfiguration":  null,
    "AzureFileShareConfiguration":  {
                                        "Accountkey":  "<key>",
                                        "AccountName":  "cluster3030",
                                        "AzureFileUrl":  "\\url",
                                        "MountOptions":  null,
                                        "RelativeMountPath":  "Y"
                                    },
    "CifsMountConfiguration":  null,
    "NfsMountConfiguration":  null
}
```

I can copy and paste this json text as a single line into the field, however it gives the following error when provisioning a node: [Scrnsht of error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab7ry.png) Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has been a hurdle for several days now.